# Creating libvirt "mcast" networks using virt-install?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I would like to create virtual machines with [mast](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSMulticast) network interfaces.  This is possible to by first creating a guest using `virt-install`, then modifying the domain XML.

Is there a way to do this from the command line?  Naively starting with:

```
virt-install -w mcast ...
```

Results in:

```
ERROR    internal error: No <source> 'port' attribute specified with socket interface
```

The XML generated by the above looks like:

```
<interface type="mcast">
  <mac address="52:54:00:21:ec:7c"/>
</interface>
```

...so it is indeed missing the `source` element.  However, the obvious solution doesn't work:

```
virt-install -w mcast,source=230.0.0.1:5555
```

That results in the same XML.

Is there a way to make this work from the `virt-install` command line?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better answer out there, but what I've settled on is:

```
virt-install -r 512 -n myguest \
  --disk vol=default/centos-base.qcow2 --import \
  -w user -w mcast,model=virtio --print-xml |
awk '{print} /interface.*type="mcast"/ {print "<source address=\"239.0.0.1\" port=\"8000\"/>"}' |
virsh create /dev/stdin
```

The above results in:

```
<interface type='mcast'>
  <source address='239.0.0.1' port='8000'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>
```

While normally I would shudder at using `awk` to process XML, in this
case the output from libvirt is very predictable.

Comment: I've even used `sed` to hack libvirt XML in a similar manner.